# Following iOS design patterns with Mac OSX programming

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I have been developing iOS applications and am familiar with starting my application off with an AppDelegate, and a ViewController with an associated xib file.

I've just created an OSX app, and to start off I am given an AppDelegate, and a window.

I wanted to keep my app design similar to what I'm familiar with so I created an NSViewController object and created an associated xib.

Now I don't know where to go from here. I can construct my NSViewController in my app delegate, but how do I add its xib to my window?

Further more - is the way I'm trying to do things "correct"?

Thanks.

Comment: You're using IB right?

Comment: Yes I am using IB. Anoop Vaidya's answer below seems to answer my question. Now that I've set the files owner, I can Ctrl+Drag to/from my UI items to wire up the outlets/actions to my newly created NSViewController rather than only to the App Delegate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking to change the File's owner you need to do similarly as ios, select the Class value from Interface Builder, change it to your required class. Now that will be your owner class.

Comment: Excellent. I think that's exactly what I needed. I have changed the File's Owner of the MainMenu.xib file that gets created to be my newly made NSViewController and now I can wire up my outlets and actions from that window. Thank you!

Comment: You should accept the answer (click the check next to the question) if it solved your problem!

Comment: @ChristianStewart: Its upto him, as he said it worked. And as you must be knowing user can only accpet the answer after 15minutes of posting the question, it gets blocked till then.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Thanks for letting me know... I forgot about the time limit, and thought I'd just remind him nicely!

Answer (score 1):

While Interface Builder for iOS and OS X may share many of the same concepts, the fundamental design of Cocoa and Cocoa-Touch has some striking differences.  NSViewController is a lot less useful API-wise than UIViewController (for instance, `-viewDidLoad` is not a method of NSViewController).  Views are typically owned by the window, and NSWindowControllers serve the same basic function in OS X, especially because they do inform you of the creation and release of their window, and consequently, their view.  I feel they would be a more appropriate replacement for the UIViewController you're used to.

Answer (score 0):

In Mac OS X GUI programming, it's a little different from creating GUIs for iPhone. You're expected to drag in GUI elements to the window (as you can also do with the top bar), and link these to public variables in your code (represented by NSObjects).

Comment: The interface builder for iOS and OS X is the same.  I'm not sure why you're making the actions you do in both of them out to be different.

Comment: They're not different.... My answer was misinformed, the original poster should accept @Anoop's answer